# How does java get an index of a database table and distinguish between a unique index and a full-text index

Tags: java, mysql, database, indexing, ddl

I want to get all the information about the database table to generate a DDL statement, but there is no way to tell if the index is a full-text index.

```
    // 获取连接
    Connection conn = sqlSessionFactory.openSession().getConnection();
    // 获取元数据
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
    String catalog = conn.getCatalog();
    String schema = conn.getSchema();
    ResultSet rs = metaData.getIndexInfo(catalog, schema, tableName, false, false);
    String indexName = rs.getString("INDEX_NAME");
    String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    boolean unique = rs.getBoolean("NON_UNIQUE");
    int type = rs.getShort("TYPE");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats
    WHERE table_name = 'mytablename';
```

Then see if it has an `index_name` of `FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX` and a `stat_description` of `FTS_DOC_ID`.

(That works in MySQL 8.0; I don't know about older versions or MariaDB.)